# PHP python NLTK integration

Tags: python, php, laravel, nltk

I have server in PHP so I'm in the need of a sentence tokenizer so the best until now that I tested was NLTK for python. I used Symphony/Process do the call the script. I couldn't pass long strings so created a temporary file to send the text for the parser.
The problem is mostly is to parse the end result. But I also wish for opinions to better my code

function that calls the python script:

```
private function parserText($text)
    {
        
        $path = base_path('py');
        $data = fopen("{$path}\\tmp.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($data, $text);
        fclose($data);
        $process = new Process(["python", "{$path}\\nltk_sentpunk.py"]);
        $process->run();

        
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
        return $process->getOutput();
    }
```

python script:

```
import sys
import os
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer, PunktParameters
os.environ['APPDATA']=r"PATH"

with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "tmp.txt"), "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

punkt_param = PunktParameters()
abbreviation = ['u.s.a', 'e.g']
punkt_param.abbrev_types = set(abbreviation)
# Training a new model with the text.
tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(punkt_param)
tokenizer.train(text)

# It automatically learns the abbreviations.
tokenizer._params.abbrev_types

# Use the customized tokenizer.
sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
print(sentences)
```

It keeps returning a string like this(some text that I'm using to test the parser):

```
"['Fees; Collection of Fees.', 'The fees we charge for using our Services and other cost structures can be found on our Policy Pages.', 'When you provide Turo a payment method, you authorize Turo, or third-party service providers acting on Turo’s behalf, to store your payment credential for future use in the event you owe Turo any money.', 'You authorize Turo to use stored payment credentials for balances, including for Trip Costs, payment, fines and fees (e.g., late fees, security deposits, processing fees and claims costs and related administrative fees).', 'Turo and its partners will employ all legal methods available to collect the amounts, including the engagements of collection agencies or legal counsel.', 'Turo, or the collection agencies we retain, may also report information about your Turo Account to credit bureaus, and as a result, late payments, missed payments, or other defaults on your Turo Account may be reflected in your credit report.', 'In addition to the amount due, delinquent accounts and/or chargebacks will be charged with fees and/or charges that are incidental to the collection of delinquent accounts and/or chargebacks including, but not limited to, collection fees, convenience fees, and/or other third party charges.', 'You hereby explicitly agree that all communication in relation to delinquent accounts may be made by e-mail or phone, as provided to Turo by you.', 'Such communication may be made by Turo or by anyone on its behalf, including but not limited to a third-party collection agent.', 'If you wish to dispute the information Turo reported to a credit bureau (i.e., Experian, Equifax, or TransUnion) please contact support.turo.com.', 'If you wish to dispute the information a collection agency reported to a credit bureau regarding your Turo Account, you must contact the collection agency directly.', 'Any use of referral travel credit is governed by the terms and conditions outlined in this policy.']\r\n"
```

I tried with json_decode with no success even if a remove the last char \r\n
I just wanna know if someone would know how to better resolve this problem.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the quotation marks in your python output. A single quotation mark is unavailable while decoding and will cause syntax errors. It would be best if you imported the JSON library in your python code, replace the last line with:

```
print(json.encode(sentences))
```